# Time evolution of $\pi/2$ pulses

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, quantum-information

This is the topic Ramsey interferometry. I want to do this without referencing the Bloch sphere, just with the Hamiltonian (given on Wikipedia and below) and Time-Dependent Schrodinger Equation.

A $\pi/2$ pulse in a two-level system is defined as a pulse that sends the excited and ground states as follows,

$$| g \rangle \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}( | g \rangle+| e \rangle).$$

$$| e \rangle \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}( -| g \rangle+| e \rangle).$$

And the Hamiltonian of the system is given as follows:
$$\hat H =\frac{-\hbar}2 (\begin{matrix} -A & B \\ B & A\end{matrix})$$

So the eigenvalues/vectors are
$$E_{1,2}= \pm \hbar C/2$$
$$|\psi_{1,2} \rangle = (A \mp C,-B)$$
Where $$C = \sqrt{A^2+B^2}$$

Two $\pi/2$ pulses are given at $t=0$ and $t=\tau$. How do I find the final wavefunction after both pulses have been applied $| \psi(t>\tau) \rangle = c_g(t)| g \rangle  + c_e(t) | e \rangle  $?

My question is mainly: what time evolution operators do you apply and when, and when do you apply the unitary operator of the $\pi/2$ pulse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is mainly: what time evolution operators do you apply and when, and when do you apply the unitary operator of the /2
> π
> /
> 2
> pulse?

You apply the unitary time evolution operator in between the $\pi/2$-pulses. This is in the order that they physically happen during a Ramsey sequence. The evolution of the state can then be written as

$$|\text{out}\rangle=U_{\pi/2}U(t)U_{\pi/2}|\text{in}\rangle,$$
where $U(t)$ is the free evolution of the atom in-between the $\pi/2$-pulses. One is then normally concerned with something such as the difference in population between the ground and excited state or the population in just one. For the difference, one would then measure
$$|\langle\text{out}|\sigma_z|\text{out}\rangle|^2,$$
where $\sigma_z=|e\rangle\langle e|-|g\rangle\langle g|$. The same can be done for $|c_{g,e}(t)|^2$ the correct operator just needs to be used in the above, i.e. $|e\rangle\langle e|$ or $|g\rangle\langle g|$.

Comment: Why do you need to use the free evolution time operator only? Ie if A was not much less than B, would the time evolution operator of the full Hamiltonian be relevant, and when would it be applied?